# Vue Router for a div

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vue-router

i have a  **home.vue** component and inside the template i have multiple div’s with class names and ids and i have navigation links which i wanted to click and route to that certain div using the classnames or id’s is there anyway to do using vue-router ?

i tried out to use

```
 <li><router-link to="#about" >About Us</router-link></li>
```

for routing it to **#aboutus**  `id` of the `div` 
but i cannot do it and i searched internet , didnt find any useful resource help me out .
[check out the imgur image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xe9NR.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need vue router for this. All you are doing is trying to scroll to a div on your page so why not try something like this:

```
<li>
   <a href="#" @click.prevent="goToDiv"><span>Go To</span></a>
</li>
```

and in your script:

```
methods: {
    goToDiv() {
      var elmnt = document.getElementById("yourId");
      elmnt.scrollIntoView();
    },
}
```